# Accessibility in Compose Multiplatform for iOS platform is not working

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

While working on the Compose KMM implementation, I found an issue with the accessibility. The Compose Multiplatform doesn’t support the accessibility directly. I tried to implement the accessibility in the respective platform module and send the event to the shared module to let the shared module screen know the accessibility is ON.

In Android, I was able to implement it, by having the accessibility check in the androidApp module and send the event to the shared module when the talkback is turned on. I was able to consume that event and show the respective accessibility UI.

In iOS, the Accessibility Inspector in iOS does not recognise the Compose UI that is displayed on the screen. It focuses on the entire screen and dictate as “Description for the element unavailable” . I was not able to focus on the internal compose UI that is drawn on the screen.

Is there any way I can focus on the Compose UI in iOS screen?

Comment: Compose for iOS is at quite early stage right now, I guess supporting accessibility has low priority, until other major issues are resolved. You can create an issue on the github repository, but I would not expect it to become available at least until the first release.

Answer (score 1):

Integration of Compose Multiplatform with iOS Accessibility is not implemented at the moment, but it's our focus in coming milestone, so stay tuned.